# Where can I find some articles and lecture notes in renorming theory in Banach spaces?

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces

I am really into renorming theory in Banach spaces especially, renorming in non-reflexive Banach spaces such that they have nice property, for example they have fixed point property,locally uniformly rotund, etc. I'd like to know

> Where can  I  find  some articles and lecture notes in renorming theory in Banach spaces?

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why doesn't it suffice to type the relevant words into a search engine?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because I don't understand why the OP is unable to perform his or her own literature search

Comment: @Dear Yemon Choi, thank you, I can to find useful document and literature but I believe that using other people experience can be very useful

Comment: Thank you for your comment. However, you do not actually ask for any particular kind of articles and notes, or about a particular set of results and problems. Your question in its current form just says "where can I find stuff" and so I don't think it really shows enough prior effort

Comment: For example, your older question http://mathoverflow.net/questions/219894/best-way-to-find-recent-papers-in-a-special-field-of-mathematics shows that you are aware of how to find articles or references to articles. It is surely up to you to look at them, look at the articles listed in the references, find articles which cite them, and so on

Answer (score 1):

Overview of older work: [Smoothness and renormings in Banach spaces](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470220880)(1993).

More recent survey:

[Some Classical and Recent Results Concerning Renorming Theory](http://thaijmath.in.cmu.ac.th/index.php/thaijmath/article/viewFile/285/416) (2012)

Answer (score 0):

If you have an access to MathSciNet, you can search, for example, for ANYWHERE "renorming" AND ANYWHERE "Banach" AND ANYWHERE "space", and then look through the obtained list (now it contains 450 titles) to find the things which you need.

Comment: I think this is the same as what I was suggesting...

Comment: @Yemon Choi Of course, this is just a detailed explanation of one of the options. At some point everyone has to learn how to do searches. But you are right, the MO is not a right place for this.